# Batch file - wait or quit if a process running

Tags: batch, process, batch-file

I have 2 small batch files that change the target location of a junction point (mkref /d), in order to switch between 2 iTunes libraries.

It works well, but I would like it to stop if iTunes is already running - as iTunes will overwrite the library in the wrong target folder if I change the junction while it is running.

Is there a way to quit or pause the batch file if iTunes.exe is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to the beginning of your batch files:

```
tasklist /fi "Imagename eq itunes.exe" 2>NUL | find /i /n "itunes.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" exit
```

For more information, see the documentation on the [tasklist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx) and [find](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490906) commands.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! And with a few GOTOs and TIMEOUT, I made it wait and re-attempt every 5 seconds until iTunes.exe is closed.